# Single background image for multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, background, navigation

I've created a simple navigation application, which alternates between two views through the use of push/popViewController. I've decided to add a background image, rather than a pattern or single colour, to both view controllers.

Is there a way to have the same backgrounds for both views, without them scrolling when the view changes? This way, it will look like the background stays still, while everything else slides over the top.

I haven't found any help on this issue, and the only idea I've come up with up to now is to attempt to use the app delegate (or, tenuously, the navigation controller) to draw the background, but my attempts to do such have all failed terribly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to add image to application `window` and set background color for both `viewcontrollers` to `clearColor`.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. However, then I had issues with changing orientation, (and also depth ordering, but I presume I could have fixed that) since the app delegate doesn't have a changeOrientation method.

Comment: You can access window subviews easily: `UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]; UIView *aView = [[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0];` so you can do anything you want with that image.

Comment: Okay, this seems to work. After a bit of tweaking, I managed to get the background working. I'll still need to implement some sort of transformation method, since simply changing the frame will have the image the right size, but facing the wrong direction. Overall, though, this is working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "root" view controller that manages all other view controllers in your app.

1. Create a view controller (with the background image as its view) and add it to the window.
2. Instantiate your navigation controller and then `[rootVC.view addSubview:navController.view]`.

**Caveat:** This should work, but "nesting" view controllers like this isn't really good practice. Read the discussion [Abusing UIViewControllers](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/), and search for "[UIViewController Containment](http://www.google.de/?q=UIViewController+Containment)" for how to do it properly in iOS 5.